# Integrate flex 3.5 projects in flash builder 4 beta 2

Tags: flex3, flexbuilder

I'm currently using Flex Builder 3 and Flex SDK 3.5 for my projects. But I'd like to try out the new Flash Builder 4. So I downloaded and installed the new software, configured all the additional software like subversion, server adapter .. and finally a importet my 2 projects.

1) Main Project  (includes a swc generated by the Library Project) (flex sdk 3.5)
2) Library Project (flex sdk 3.4)

After the import and project cleanup the project is running perfectly. But as soon as I replace the existing LibraryProject.swc through a new one (compiled with flash builder 4 beta 2 sdk 3.4)

VerifyError: Error #1014: class mx.containers::Canvas not found.
VerifyError: Error #1014: class mx.containers::HBox not found.
VerifyError: Error #1014: class IWatcherSetupUtil not found.
... and several others not found errors.

Does anyone has the same error. How can I get my project running again?

Answer (score 0):

I would first check the Properties of both project very carefully. Things that are important:

In your Main project (containing the actual Application)

- Flex Build Path -> Library Path Check if the import order is correct and try to change it according to your dependencies)
- Flex Compiler (check the SDK!)

In your Library

- Flex Library Build Path -> Classes (see if everything ic checked what you need, except if you are using MAVEN with flexmojos.
- Flex Library Build Path -> Library Path (again, the order is very important if you are using 3rd party stuff)

I take it that both, your application and your swc are built within the same IDE with the same SDK version. Of course, theoretically it should be downwards compatible, but thats only true in every case for some parallel universe :-).

Comment: Tried it out now several times. But it ends up always in the same error.

Comment: yeah, I just ran into the very same problem today several times. It seesm if I do the right stuff in the right order, it is still generated. But as soon as I click something wrong (dont ask me :-) ) the bin-debug will be empty forever...

Comment: Finally I resolved it ;)... I removed all the libraries in the project. Compiled the project .. and then added one by another library... and then it worked again.